# WiX find usergroup on non-english OS

Tags: localization, wix

I need to find the local Administrators group in a WiX installer in order to add a user to that group. This should work in a localized way according to the OS the installer is running under. I have tried several approaches, like

```
<util:Group Id="AdministratorsGroup" Domain="[Computername]" Name="Administrators"/>
```

This, however, will yield the desired user group on an english OS only, as in german for example "Administrators" is written "Administratoren" (other languages accordingly), and the above code will not work.

I also tried:

```
<util:Group Id="AdministratorsGroup" Domain="BUILTIN" Name="Administrators"/>
```

and

```
<util:Group Id="AdministratorsGroup" Name="BUILTIN\Administrators"/>
```

which simply leads to an error during execution, stating that the group could not be found.

It would be possible to use a Custom Action, which I would like not to do. Also, I tried to translate "Administrators" to the appropriate language and than using $(loc.Administrators), but this appears more like a hack to me (sorry).

Can any one give a hint, which name or property in WiX will yield the correct result? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try using WIX_ACCOUNT_ADMINISTRATORS, which is a WiX property that will return the localized text.

```
<util:Group Id="AdministratorsGroup" Name="[WIX_ACCOUNT_ADMINISTRATORS]"/>
```

Comment: thx for the reply :) I forgot to mention in my question that I already tried that, too. The installation fails with that, because WIX_ACCOUNT_ADMINISTRATORS evaluates to an empty string. Am I missing some declaration elsewhere to get it working?

Comment: You need <PropertRef Id="WIX_ACCOUNT_ADMINISTRATORS"/> to define the custom actions that set the property to a value.